# R: qPlot how reduce intervals x-axle

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, distribution

when I try to create an histogram for my data with:

```
qplot(data$time1, geom="histogram", main="Histogramm Renndauerverteilung 1. Runde", 
      ylab="Anzahl Rennpferde", xlab= "Zeit in Sekunden")
```

the following on the image happens:

[image: Histogram for my data]

It is because I have in this variable a number, which doesn't make sense (999):

```
summary(data$time1)    
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#  12.39    14.12   24.18   21.14   25.36  999.00
```

I want my histogram (x-axle) to show the distribution between 12 and 30. 
I imagine there is a simple solution, but as I'm not experienced with R, could you please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try `xlim= c(0,30)` in your `qplot()` function

Comment: @MichaelVine it worked, thanks a lot!!